# Change the order of navigation in my account page in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I add new link **Offline Order** in my account page in frontend on my account page .

its add successfully in the navigation

but its show in **last** in the menu.

i want to add **offline order** link after **my order**

my code given below where i add link in navgation link

```
    <reference name="customer_account_navigation">

          <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="offorder"><name>offlineorders</name><path>offorder/offorder/history</path><label>My OfflineOrder</label></action>

    </reference>

</customer_account>
```

What i have to do for change the link order ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "out of the box" way of doing this, unless you put your code in the `sales.xml` layout file right under the link you want.
This is because the `Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Navigation` block that handles the customer account menu does not have a way to sort the links. See the method that adds links:

```
public function addLink($name, $path, $label, $urlParams=array())
{
    $this->_links[$name] = new Varien_Object(array(
        'name' => $name,
        'path' => $path,
        'label' => $label,
        'url' => $this->getUrl($path, $urlParams),
    ));
    return $this;
}
```

There is an other option, to override the block mentioned above and in the method `getLinks`, instead of returning the links, you can arrange the first. But I wouldn't go there.

Comment: i add the link in customer account page its add sucessfully but its show in the last i need show it after myorder so what i have to do

Comment: That is what I explained. You need to take this line `<action method="addLink" translate="label" module="offorder"><name>offlineorders</name><path>offorder/offorder/history</path><label>My OfflineOrder</label></action>` and add it in the `sales.xml` layout file, right under the link you want it to appear. There is no way to order the links. They are shown in the order they are parsed.

Comment: but what when i have to create customized module for client than i have to change in core file???

Comment: Not necessarily a core file. It can be the `sales.xml` layout file in your custom theme. If you don't want that, there is the option to override `Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Navigation` and make your logic for adding the link or sort the links before retrieving them. Read the answer carefully.

Answer (score 1):

The `<position>` method is not working for me at all.

As a workaround, I've used the `<addLink>` method where the account navigation block is first populated with links

In my case that's in

```
<customer_account translate="label">
  <!-- -->
  <reference name="left">
     <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account</name><path>customer/account/</path><label>My Account</label></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="myModule"><name>myLInk</name><path>my/path/</path><label>My Link</label></action>
     </block>
  </reference>
  <!-- -->
</customer_account>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the order by changing the number here in the XML's

So if you want sales order history to be next to My dashboard you'd need to change 220 to 240. Its 240 because the dashboard order number is 250.

sales/order/history
                    Order History
                    220

Answer (score -1):

for changing the order of navigation in my account

for example you want to change myaccount link go to layout->customer.xml

add this line

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
```

here in position will define you links sort order you will have to change position of every link like for my orders(for that you will have to change sales.xml)